# The key attribute, and docs on LWC Virtual DOM

Tags: lightning-web-components, dom

Per the [LWC docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_lists) we have the following:

> When a list changes, the framework uses the key to rerender only the
>   item that changed. The key in the template is used for performance
>   optimization and isn’t reflected in the DOM at run time.

Questions related to the above:

1. Is there any sort of documentation / whitepaper on the LWC
   implementation of Virtual DOM? That description of key and
   performance optimization is vague and I feel like there's a lot to
   unpack under the hood. I figure understanding LWC Virtual DOM could
   be the right place to start.
2. If the key is not reflected in the DOM at run time, is they value of
   the key still being "downloaded" (for back of a letter word) by the
   client? It sounds like it's being used client-side for performance
   optimization, but if it's not available in the DOM at all I'm having
   a hard time envisioning how that works.

I recognize that I don't have to understand everything under the hood to use LWC, but I think that understanding at least some framework details can help drive better implementations in the long haul.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a library used called [Snabbdom](https://github.com/snabbdom/snabbdom/) for the VDOM. It's short, elegant, and will probably give you most of what you need to know.

At a high level, there are VNode elements that are placed in a VDOM (Virtual DOM). Changes to a `@track`ed member will set a dirty flag, which in turn will update the VDOM, which in turn updates the DOM. The key itself is stored in the VNode, which is why it does not appear in the DOM.

The VNode also has a link to the DOM element, thus allowing the relationship between the two to be maintained. From what I can tell, the framework only updates the VDOM, which itself is then responsible for updating the DOM. This should mostly make sense if you check the documentation for Snabbdom.

The components themselves are compiled into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), which is demonstrated in the [lwc open source library](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc). This is very sparsely documented/commented, however, so it may take a while to process how it all starts. Starting with the VDOM library first should help put everything into perspective.

As a side node, most (all?) of the LWC framework (aside from unit testing) is in TypeScript, so if you're not familiar with it, you'll need to [do some more reading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Comment: Thanks @sfdxfox, accepting this answer